# Custom Xsession with Gnome visuals

Tags: 10.04, xorg, kiosk

I'm trying to create a kiosk PC only for web browsing using [this tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/) as a reference (only difference - I'm using Firefox instead of Chromium)

It is working correctly in principle (only FF window opens when I log in using the Kiosk session) but it looks, well, super ugly. The scrollbar and right-click context menus look like from the 1990s - gray and boxy.

How could I modify the session to get Gnome-like scrollbars/menus without the whole Gnome desktop (top/bottom panel etc)?

My custom X session is currently set up like this:

**/usr/share/xsessions/kiosk.desktop**:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Kiosk Mode
Comment=Firefox Kiosk Mode
Exec=/usr/share/xsessions/ffKiosk.sh
Type=Application
```

**/usr/share/xsessions/ffKiosk.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do firefox -height 768 -width 1024; sleep 1s; done
```

Answer (score 3):

In `/usr/share/xsessions/ffKiosk.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-settings-daemon &
while true ; do firefox -height 768 -width 1024 ; sleep 1s ; done
```